# PHPUnit Error : Class 'ClassName' not found

Tags: php, phpunit, php-7.4

I started to use PHPUnit today. But I have a problem. So my project structure is like:

```
<ul>
  <li>source
    <ul>
      <li>Team.php and other classes</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>test
    <ul>
      <li>TeamTest.php</li>
</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
    <?php


    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;


    class TeamTest extends TestCase {
        private Team $team;

        public function setUp(): void {
            $this->team = new Team(0);
        }
    }
```

but when I run the test It gives me error:

```
Error : Class 'Team' not found
 C:\Users\16044\PhpstormProjects\tesl\test\TeamTest.php:11
```

I couldnt find any resolution as I tried to add `use Team` but PHPStorm told me that I dont need that import somehow. Im new in php programming and dont know bunch of stuff sorry if this is a silly question but any help would be appreciated :)

Edit: Found out that if I use this:
`require '..\source\Team.php'` tests work but do I need to do this for every test? Or is there a problem with my work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PhpStorm does not recognize properties type hinting for PHP 7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59029713/phpstorm-does-not-recognize-properties-type-hinting-for-php-7-4)

Comment: No this is a problem with PHPUnit not with phpstorm

Comment: Does it work with the `use` statement? I think Dharman's pointing to the PHPStorm question is because it is an error that the editor is saying you don't need the use statement when you really do because it doesn't yet recognise the 7.4 property typehint

Comment: It doesnt work in both ways. "use Team;" doesnt work too. Maybe I should specify directory names?

Comment: You need to specify the whole namespace if you're bringing a class in a different directory/namespace